# Hidden field is not sent to service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, submit, hidden-field

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 webpage where I use the following HTML code to generate a form for enduser :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("JEdit", "Post", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmEditPost" }))
{

    <div id="postListEditor" class="regularContainer" style="position:relative;">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
        @Html.HiddenFor(c=> c.Id, false)
        <div class="floatLeft">
            @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Title, true)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Title, new { @class = "tb1", @Style = "width:400px;" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <br style="clear:both;" />
        <div class="floatLeft">
            @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Text, true)
            @Html.TextAreaFor(c => c.Text, new { @class = "tb1", @Style = "width:400px; height:200px" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text)
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        @Html.Raw(@Html.SubmitButton("Posta", "btPost", "", "", "ValidateFormAndAjaxSubmit('frmEditPost', this);"))
    </div>
}
```

When clicking the submitbutton the following javascript will be runned :

```
function ValidateFormAndAjaxSubmit(formId, callingElement) {

    if (IsNotDblClick(callingElement.id)) {
        var _form = $("#" + formId);

        var validator = _form.validate();
        var anyError = false;

        anyError = !_form.valid();

        if (anyError) {
            window.latestClick = '';
            return false; // exit if any error found    
        }

        $.post(_form.attr("action"), _form.serialize(), function (data) {

            if (data.success && data.redirectUrl.length > 0) {
                window.location.href = data.redirectUrl;
            }
            else {

                var isValid = validateResponse(_form, data);

                window.latestClick = '';
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The problem is that the hiddenFor is never sent back but all other members are? I can see in the generated HTML that the hitten field is set like this :

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Int32 must be a number." data-val-required="The Int32 field is required." id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="21">
```

So why is this hittenField not sent back to the service?

**Edit1 :** 
This is sent according to dev in Chrome

```
Request URL:http://localhost:5215/Post/JEdit
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin:http://localhost:5215
Referer:http://localhost:5215/Post/Edit/42
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
Id:42
Title:testar3532
Text:testas3532
Url:http://test.se
Tags:
```

**Edti2 :**

This is how the ViewModel looks like :

```
public class EditPostViewModel
    {
        public int Id = -1;

        public EditPostViewModel() { }
        public EditPostViewModel(string title, string text, string url)
        {
            Title = title;
            Text = text;
            Url = url;
        }

        [Display(Name = "Titel"/*Description = "..."*/)]
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "...")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage="...")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Text")]
        [StringLength(2500, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "...")]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "...")]
        [Display(Name = "Länk")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(http(s)?://([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=])?)?$", ErrorMessage="...")]
        public string Url { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Tags")]
        [TagAttribute(ErrorMessage="...a")]
        public string Tags { get; set; }

        public List<int> TagIdList { get; set; }

        public string CustomError { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Use Fiddler to verify that it really isn't being sent.

Comment: Why are you passing `false` as the second argument? If anything that should be an anonymous object for HTML attributes. If you don't need extra attributes, don't pass a second argument.

Comment: @Bryan, that was just a test, if I remove it there will still not be any id sent back to the service.

Comment: @usr Pleas check Edit1, the id is sent.

Comment: @SnowJim what does that test result tell you?

Comment: @usr That the data is sent to the service but is is not parsed into the object. I do however not see why, the name of the property is correct and its not a complexed type.

Comment: @usr Pleas see Edit2.

Comment: @SnowJim well done :) This piece of debugging got you an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC cannot bind to fields by default. Only properties. So change your `Id` member to a property.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.Id, new { Value = Model.Id })

Comment: Should your hiddeninput already have an id, or are you inserting a new record?